# Load Chrome extension outside of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to run an chrome extension outside of Google Chrome?

I copied the source code of an extension but when I run it, nothing happens. If it is loaded inside of Google Chrome, it loads properly. Is there a condition or something that checks if the extension is being opened by Chrome that doesn't let it load properly outside of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

Can you just double click the html file and expect it to work? No.
Can you make it so you can open the extension from a desktop icon or the [App Launcher](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en)? Yes. See [Chrome Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)

I think you're trying to do the first thing, so no, you can't do that. Chrome extensions and apps rely on API that is not exposed to other websites or scripts.